# Retrieving user email & display name from Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, tfs

My goal is to retrieve the whole email addresses of the whole usesr in a TFS.
I finally success to get the SID list of the users, but I dont think its ok because there are groups in the group that I retrieve the SID and I dont know how to get access to it.
here's the important part in my code, hope to get the answer here how to do it.

```
  TeamFoundationIdentity[] projectGroups = _ims.ListApplicationGroups(projectUri, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, object> descSet = new Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, object>(IdentityDescriptorComparer.Instance);

            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity projectGroup in projectGroups)
            {
                descSet[projectGroup.Descriptor] = projectGroup.Descriptor;
            }

            // Expanded membership of project groups
            projectGroups = _ims.ReadIdentities(descSet.Keys.ToArray(), MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            // Collect all descriptors
            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity projectGroup in projectGroups)
            {
                foreach (IdentityDescriptor mem in projectGroup.Members)
                {
                    TeamFoundationIdentity[] _identities = _ims.ReadIdentities(new IdentityDescriptor[] {mem}, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                   foreach(TeamFoundationIdentity id in _identities)
                   {
                      //the sid
                      Console.WriteLine(id.Descriptor.Identifier);
                   }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to get all user of a TeamProjectCollection:

```
IGroupSecurityService gss = (IGroupSecurityService)tfsConnection.GetService(typeof(IGroupSecurityService));
Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);
Identity[] UserId = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.None);

foreach (Identity user in UserId)
{    
 // check if group or user
 if (!user.SecurityGroup)
 {
  Console.Writeln(user.DisplayName +" -> "+ user.Domain + "\" + user.AccountName + "-" + user.MailAddress);
 }
}
```

So first I get all users of Valid Users group (including the groups), using recursive flag `QueryMembership.Expanded`. Than convert the list of SIDs of the Members to a list of identities of users, which have all the information in a readable way.

Comment: It works, but IGroupSecurityService is now obsolete.